# Why does Oracle ODP.Net automattically commit inserted records when using parameter array binding?

Tags: arrays, oracle, binding, parameters, odp.net

Strange issue. I have a managed OPD.Net application that calls a stored procedure to insert records. When I call the procedure normally and rollback the transaction, the records are not saved to the table (duh!). When I use the procedure with parameter array binding and still roll back the transaction, the records ARE saved to the table. Somehow, the records are getting committed even though I do a rollback!

TEST Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
   ID NUMBER(15,0),
   VALUE VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
)
/

CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_ID_SEQ
  INCREMENT BY 1
  START WITH 50
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999
  NOCYCLE
  NOORDER
  CACHE 100
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_INSERT
(
   iVALUE IN VARCHAR2,
   oID OUT NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
    oID := TEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    INSERT INTO TEST
    (
      ID,
      VALUE
    )
    VALUES
    (
      oID,
      iVALUE
    );
END;
/
```

Test Code:

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace OdpTestArrayBinding
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string cConnectioString = "Data Source=DB_DEV;User Id=TMP;Password=sqlsql";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OracleConnection lConnectionA = new OracleConnection(cConnectioString))
            {
                lConnectionA.StateChange += ConnectionStateChanged;
                lConnectionA.Open();
                Console.WriteLine($"[Connection={lConnectionA.GetHashCode()}] Connection opened.");
                int lStartCount = CountTestTableRows(lConnectionA);
                Console.WriteLine($"[Connection={lConnectionA.GetHashCode()}] Number of rows in table at start is {lStartCount}.");
                using (OracleTransaction lTransaction = lConnectionA.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"[Connection={lConnectionA.GetHashCode()}] Transaction started.");
                    try
                    {
                        using (OracleCommand lCmd = new OracleCommand())
                        {
                            lCmd.Connection = lConnectionA;
                            lCmd.BindByName = true;
                            lCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            lCmd.CommandText = "TEST_INSERT";

                            lCmd.Parameters.Add("iVALUE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
                            // The OracleDbType of the output does not seem to matter, the actual value is always OracleDecimal
                            lCmd.Parameters.Add("oID", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output);

                            lCmd.ArrayBindCount = 3;

                            lCmd.Parameters["iVALUE"].Value = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Boo" };
                            // Not required.
                            //lCmd.Parameters["oID"].Value = new long[] { -1, -1, -1 }; 

                            lCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            OracleDecimal[] lOutIds = (OracleDecimal[])lCmd.Parameters["oID"].Value;
                            Console.WriteLine($"[Connection={lConnectionA.GetHashCode()}] Inserted 3 rows using stored procedure, out ID vales are {string.Join(",", lOutIds)}.");
                        }
                        ListRows(lConnectionA, lStartCount + 3);

                        using (OracleConnection lConnectionB = new OracleConnection(cConnectioString))
                        {
                            lConnectionB.StateChange += ConnectionStateChanged;
                            lConnectionB.Open();
                            Console.WriteLine($"[Connection={lConnectionB.GetHashCode()}] Connection opened.");
                            ListRows(lConnectionB, lStartCount);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        lTransaction.Rollback();
                        Console.WriteLine($"[Connection={lConnectionA.GetHashCode()}] Transaction rolled back.");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press the ENTER key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ConnectionStateChanged(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Connection={sender.GetHashCode()}] State changed from {e.OriginalState} to {e.CurrentState}.");
        }

        private static int CountTestTableRows(OracleConnection aConnection)
        {
            using (OracleCommand lCmd = new OracleCommand())
            {
                lCmd.Connection = aConnection;
                lCmd.BindByName = true;
                lCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                lCmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST";
                return Convert.ToInt32(lCmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }

        private static void ListRows(OracleConnection aConnection, int aExpectedRowCount)
        {
            int lCount = CountTestTableRows(aConnection);
            Console.Write($"[Connection={aConnection.GetHashCode()}] Number of rows in table {lCount}");
            if (lCount == aExpectedRowCount)
                Console.WriteLine(" (Test passed, actual and expected row count are the same).");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($" (Test FAILED!, expected {aExpectedRowCount} rows).");
        }
    }
}
```

First run console output:

```
[Connection=47973293] State changed from Closed to Open.
[Connection=47973293] Connection opened.
[Connection=47973293] Number of rows in table at start is 0.
[Connection=47973293] Transaction started.
[Connection=47973293] Inserted 3 rows using stored procedure, out ID vales are 50,51,52.
[Connection=47973293] Number of rows in table 3 (Test passed, actual and expected row count are the same).
[Connection=21040294] State changed from Closed to Open.
[Connection=21040294] Connection opened.
[Connection=21040294] Number of rows in table 3 (Test FAILED!, expected 0 rows).
[Connection=21040294] State changed from Open to Closed.
[Connection=47973293] Transaction rolled back.
[Connection=47973293] State changed from Open to Closed.
```

I have tried Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll 4.121.2.20141216 (ODAC RELEASE 3) and 4.121.2.20150926 (ODAC RELEASE 4), both give the same result. Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: If I remove the output parameter, the data is not saved and rolled back as expected. So the issue is with managed ODP.Net and output parameters used with parameter array binding. Also tested with unmanaged ODP.Net and the problem does not happen, even with an output parameter and arraybinding. So its probably a bug in managed ODP.Net...

Comment: As far as I can tell from my own tests, if you use ArrayBinding (`DbCommand.ArrayBindCount` field), then transaction control commands such as `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` are not supported. There is a brief mention in the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/extenRest.htm#ODPNT451) that those same transaction commands are not supported for ".NET stored procedures" and my guess is that ArrayBinding also falls into that category.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to change your code to use this example.
Open only a using block for your connection.

```
public void RunOracleTransaction(string connectionString)
{
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        OracleTransaction transaction;

        // Start a local transaction
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText = 
                "INSERT INTO Dept (DeptNo, Dname, Loc) values (50, 'TECHNOLOGY', 'DENVER')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText = 
                "INSERT INTO Dept (DeptNo, Dname, Loc) values (60, 'ENGINEERING', 'KANSAS CITY')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Neither record was written to database.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleaase check your command : you have forget assign the transaction on your command?

```
    lCmd.Connection = lConnectionA;
  // Assign transaction to your command
   lCmd.Transaction = lTransaction;
```

Comment: Well spotted and tried it but does not solve the problem, same error happens. Never had to assign this property before and it seems to default to the current transaction for the connection which is assigned to the command.

Comment: Setting the Transaction property is not required because it is auto-enlisted from the transaction associated with the connection according to this Oracle article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o39odpnet-087387.html

Also, the Transaction property is a no-op and does not get set in ODP.NET. You can confirm this by loading up the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess driver in ILSpy (or another .NET decompiler) and navigating to the OracleCommand.Transaction property. The setter is empty.

But to answer the initial question, any use of ArrayBinding in ODP.NET will ignore transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `TransactionScope` that wraps your database connection and within your `TransactionScope`, try enlisting in the ambient transaction:

```
<your connection object>.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
```